# Type 'void | Observable<any>' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'

Tags: typescript, promise, observable, httpresponse

I get the following error from the below code:

> error TS2345: Argument of type '`(err: any) => void | Observable<any>`' is not assignable to parameter of type '`(err: any, caught: Observable<HttpEvent<any>>) => ObservableInput<any>`'.
>    Type '`void | Observable<any>`' is not assignable to type `ObservableInput<any>`'.
>       Type '`void`' is not assignable to type '`ObservableInput<any>`'

This is my code:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(this.addToken(req, this.authService.getAuthToken()))
        .catch(err => {
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                switch ((<HttpErrorResponse>err).status) {
                    case 403:
                        return this.handle403Error(req, next);
                    case 401:
                        return this.authService.logout(() => {
                            return this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth/login');
                        });
                    case 400:
                        return Observable.throw(err);
                    default:
                        return Observable.throw(err);
                }
            } else {
                return Observable.throw(err);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: this is just the error, please rephrase your question to a more proper form and include a minimal and fully working example that reproduces the error you are trying to solve as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What do `handle403Error` and `authService.logout` return?